# Why does Google Maps display strange, jagged state boundaries in the Great Lakes?

Tags: google-maps, united-states, boundaries

When I search for a state on Google Maps, I am shown the state outlined in red. I've noticed that the states that border the Great Lakes have boundaries that protrude into the lakes in strange ways.

Here are some examples:

[image]

[image]

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Google maps has huge contribution from the third party sources and crowd sourcing. Google Maps acquire these data-sets and then upload them into web application.

So, what happened here is that Google maps acquired these boundary in Zig Zag way, rather than more curved and aligned. There can be three reasons for that

1. Geography on ground could be different, maybe the reference data
   used to digitized would be like that, so they could've digitized it
   like that in a Zig zag way.
2. Reduce the number of vertices. Sometimes, we observe such
   behavior with large polygons because simplification is applied on
   the data to reduce the size and hence make faster loading on the
   client side.
3. These boundaries could've been auto generated through Image based
   classification or pixel based detection a low resolutions imagery,
   and those and the features are created from the pixels. (Maybe
   created from some world imagery)

These are some of my views about why such boundaries that occur on the Google Maps.